# В чем разница между двумя fliter для массивов?

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который работает:

```
function filter_list(l) {
return l.filter(item => typeof (item) == 'number')
}
```

И есть код, который не работает:

```
function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(function (item) {
        typeof (item) == 'number'
    })
}
```

В чем разница?
Суть задачи в том, чтобы выводить числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором случае забыли `return` перед  `typeof (item) == 'number'`

Comment: Спасибо) А если я делаю так:
`function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(function (item) {
        if (typeof (item) == 'number') {
            return item
        }
    })
}`
То выводит все числа, кроме 0

Comment: @NickRoddy а зачем так писать?

Comment: @NickRoddy потому что 0 приводится к false, используй строгие сравнения

Comment: @lezhni тут дело не только в этом. сама его запись не имеет смысла

Answer (score 1):

В данном случаи стрелочная функция без фигурных скобок. Ей не нужен return, все что будет написано там в строку - вернется.

```
function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(item => typeof (item) == 'number')
}
```

Еще это могло бы быть записано вот так вот

```
function filter_list(l) {
    return l.filter(item => { 
      return typeof (item) == 'number'
    })
}
```

Во втором случаи - это обычная функция, которой, как и написал Алексей - нужен return